# Is this the decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm using the built-in system class for sending emails in .NET. It's in System.Mail namespace or something like that.

I need to add an interface to this class so I can swap it out for testing or another implementation.

To do this, I just define a class that wraps this built-in class?

Is this an example of the decorator pattern? I'm just a bit confused because the description of the decorator pattern usually states that it is used to add functionality, and I won't be adding any.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that sounds just like encapsulation (the wrapper class) and abstraction (the interface).

However, once you *have* the interface, you could *then* use the decorator pattern.

Strictly, in decorator usage each layer has the **same** interface; the decoration is essentially a daisy-chain of different concrete classes that (when implementing the interface) either pass the method to the *next* link in the chain, or do something bespoke.

(**update**: I'm not saying you *should* do it this way - this is just an example of how the decorator pattern might work, in the context of the original e-mail question)

For example, you might have an interface `IEmail`, a basic implementation `BasicEmail` (that uses the built-in .NET code), a `LoggingEmail` that accepts an `IEmail`, and just passes things along (but logs things as you go), and a `ForwardingEmail` that accepts an `IEmail` and changes the `To` etc (perhaps for dev/test/live purposes).

Then you could have:

```
`ForwardingEmail` => `LoggingEmail` => `BasicEmail` => (regular .NET classes)
```

(where the first three are only known as `IEmail`)

This allows you to extend functionality without changing the API. Very common in factory / IoC setups, and even more so with AOP.

Comment: although I don't think you answered the exact question as clearly as I did, i bumped you one because I couldn't be bothered explaining how it should be done.  Wouldn't it be much nicer to say, just implememnt this interface and your TestMailSender class can plug in everywhere ISendMail is expected.

Comment: Just saw a downvote on this - I'd love to know why...? Any feedback?

Comment: you should be so lucky - I'll balance it with +1 for the both of you for solid answers

Comment: @annakata - the funny thing is, I'm not fussed on the votes (I'm at my daily cap anyway, so that +1 only restores the 2 points I lost ;-p) - I'd just love to hear what it is that [anon] disagrees with... Oh well, I may never know.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not the decorator pattern, it is the proxy pattern, note: I think Microsoft expects you to make your test class inherit from the SmtpClient class, and implement the Send, AsynchSend etc yourself (in a way that they just write to a text file or whatever -- if you're wanting to plug in a test version).  However if you're wanting to do it the *correct* way, not the microsoft way, do it the way Marc said.  You will find more and more examples in .NET of interfaces not being there when they should have been.

Comment: For info, I wasn't trying to say how to do it; I was simply explaining the decorator pattern in the context of the original question.